# Loopback passport login

Tags: oauth, passport.js, loopbackjs

I want to use Loopback passport to login to my app via a third party. However, rather than having anyone successfully authenticating with the third party, I want to be able to only allow those accounts with an email already configured as a user access (i.e. I want to whitelist people from this provider).

Is this possible? Almost all the examples I have seen with Loopback passport and OAuth and similar strategies more generally seem to assume that I am happy to have every Google / Facebook user access my application, whereas that is not my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [loopback-example-passport](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-passport) repository extends a few base models (User, AccessToken, UserIdentity and UserCredential).

You can create a new file `/common/models/user-identity.js`, which can listen for when new identities are created. In there try something like this:

```
module.exports = function(userIdentity) {
  userIdentity.observe('before save', function(context, next) {
    if (context.instance) {
      console.log(context.instance.profile._json);
    }
  }
}
```

Within `context.instance.profile._json`, you can observe the details of the newly created user, modify their details or remove it if needed.

Comment: Hello @J3Y your answer is very interesting, and I have a question. If I need to do a redirect to the user to inform that need an account to be able to login, how should I send the redirection? becuase I do not have access to the res object. Thanks.

Comment: @RaulVargasMuñoz You may be able to do something with the `customCallback` option, although I don't think this is documented very well. Take a look at the source code for [loopback-component-passport](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-passport/blob/master/lib/passport-configurator.js#L623).

You can provide a custom callback in the passport configuration options for a provider, and then possibly redirect as needed. The [defaultCallback](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-passport/blob/master/lib/passport-configurator.js#L492) has access to the `res` object.

Answer (score 0):

I have dived into third-party auth few weeks ago and realized that existing documentation and [loopback-example-passport](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-passport) is not enough to read in my case. For example, existing loopback-component-passport is unable to work with custom User models.

I think you can perform operation hook on your UserIdentity model and compare email from UserIdentity.profile.emails array and User model emails with find() and filter.